# Fluxbox xonfig permanen box

Tags: config, window-managers

I am using ubuntu 12.04 with fluxbox.

I want to create a permanent box at the top of the screen about 20px width to display my conky information. Fullscreen windows should stick below this bar.

What do i need to add this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [_NET_WM_STRUT_/_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#idp6336416) emwh hints.